# decrypt a saml 2.0 response having aes 128 and rsa

Tags: rsa, aes

I need to decrypt a saml 2.0 response. But, the response object has reference to aes 128 and rsa algorithms, and I am having hard time in finding a way to decrypt.

Below is the structure of the response (replacing the sensitive data with some random values)

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="" ID="_12345" InResponseTo="" IssueInstant="2015-01-01T10:00:00.000Z" Version="2.0">
<saml:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
<xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="12333" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
    <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"/>
    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:RetrievalMethod Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#EncryptedKey" URI="#12567"/>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
    <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <xenc:CipherValue xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">xxxxxxxxxxx</xenc:CipherValue>
    </xenc:CipherData>
</xenc:EncryptedData>
<xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="12567">
    <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <ds:DigestMethod xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    </xenc:EncryptionMethod>
    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:KeyValue>
            <ds:RSAKeyValue>
                <ds:Modulus>xxxxxxxxxx</ds:Modulus>
                <ds:Exponent>xxxxxxxx</ds:Exponent>
            </ds:RSAKeyValue>
        </ds:KeyValue>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
    <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <xenc:CipherValue xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">xxxxxxx</xenc:CipherValue>
    </xenc:CipherData>
    <xenc:ReferenceList>
        <xenc:DataReference URI="#12333"/>
    </xenc:ReferenceList>
</xenc:EncryptedKey>
</saml:EncryptedAssertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Now, how should I proceed with this response and the private key, I have.

I am able to decrypt the response successfully on a online tool https://www.samltool.com/decrypt.php, but I couldn't get the internals, which I need.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a programming question with no direct cryptographic content. You should ask on [so], but you need to **POST YOUR CODE**.

Comment: I am not exactly looking for a program nor logic. I want to understand the response object. How is the aes 128 and rsa relation defined and how to use modulus and exponent (theoretical explanation is sufficient) from the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a definitive answer, you really should see the documentation for the data format you're dealing with, but just quickly looking at the XML response, it would seem that you're dealing with a [hybrid encryption](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) scheme.

That is, your encrypted message consists of two parts:

1. The actual data (in `xenc:EncryptedData`), encrypted using [AES](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)-[CBC](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC_mode) with a single-use per-message key.
2. The AES key used to encrypt the data, itself encrypted (in `xenc:EncryptedKey`) with [RSA](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem))-[OAEP](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding).

The main reason for using this kind of hybrid encryption, instead of directly encrypting the data directly with RSA, is that public-key encryption algorithms like RSA tend to be rather slow, increase the message length considerably, and generally be poorly suited for encrypting long message.  They work just fine for encrypting AES keys (which are just random bitstrings 16 / 32 bytes long), though.  So we use AES to encrypt the message (which is fast and only adds a few bytes to the message length), and then encrypt the AES key with RSA so that the intended recipient can decrypt it.

Comment: Thank you, Ilmari Karonen.

What is the use of the modulus and the exponent in the saml response? Isn't the private key I have, is sufficient for decrypting? If not, how the private key, modulus and exponent can be used to decrypt?

Comment: The modulus and exponent together make up an RSA public key. You're right, you presumably don't need them for decryption, but at least you can check that they match the private key you have.

Comment: I have got the information, what I was looking for. Thank you Ilmari Karonen.